# SVG and TTF Loader in Webpack 5 Doesn't Work in SCSS files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, sass

I have tried many different combinations of loaders for both scss, svg and ttf file types but I have not been able to get webpack to be able to work with svg or ttf files loaded into scss files.

Specifically, these are the errors I am getting:

```
ERROR in ./src/scss/index.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/scss/index.scss) 17:37-93
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../assets/error-input.svg' in '.../Repos/repo/src/scss'
```

```
ERROR in ./src/scss/index.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/scss/index.scss) 6:36-93
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/RobotoMono-Light.ttf' in '.../Repos/repo/src/scss'
```

This is how these are loaded in the scss files:

```
@font-face {
  font-display: swap;
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono';
  font-weight: $font-weight-light;
  src: url('../fonts/RobotoMono-Light.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

```
$_path: '../../assets/';
...
.error-16-small {
        &::before {
          content: url('#{$_path}error-input.svg');
        }
      }
```

This is my webpack configuration:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require("webpack"); //to access built-in plugins

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.js$|jsx/, use: "babel-loader" },
      { test: /\.svg$/, use: ["svg-inline-loader", "svg-url-loader"] },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|png|jpg)$/,
        loader: "url-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: "./public/index.html" })],
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx", "..."],
    preferRelative: true,
    modules: [".", "node_modules"],
  },
};
```

I am not sure if I am getting the order of the loaders incorrect or if there is a different type of loader I should use.

Comment: Is there a reason you _need_ loaders instead of just putting your statis assets like SVG and fonts in normal asset dirs like `images` and `fonts` and pointing to their relative URL? (Also, _do not use TTF_ for your web fonts, use WOFF2. TTF files are _system_ font files, not web fonts, so they're going to be much bigger than they need to be, _and_ will get parsed much stricter than proper webfonts)

Comment: I assumed the error I was getting was specifically because there wasn't the correct loader for svg and fonts.  As far as I can see, they are just pointing to static directories but I am getting that module error still, unless I am understanding the error incorrectly.  Really, I am trying to upgrade to webpack 5 with legacy code as it stands already, so making actual code changes (like chaging the type of fonts we use) isn't in the scope of this unless absolutely necessary, though not out of the question for future changes.

Comment: you have bundling rules for svg and webfonts, so rip those out and see what happens. But also notice that if you do keep them, you have the svg extension overloaded. Also have a look at your sass config so make sure _that_ doesn't try to inline things.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the issue was how sass was importing the svgs and the ttfs once upgraded.  In some cases it was stripping out a "/" from the path where expected, and in other cases relative paths no longer worked and had to be replaced with absolute paths.  This was not ideal as we wanted to avoid making code changes but there was no way around it.